# Measure time execution of function

Tags: python

What is the best (precise) way to measure time execution of function, for example:

```
def some_function():
    # ...
```

I would prefer call this function 1000 times and then count average time, like this:

```
start = time.time()

for i in range(1000):
    some_function()

elapsed = (time.time() - start)/1000
```

but maybe is there better way?

Comment: use the timeit module is my recomendation ...

Comment: cprofile is also very informative ... but doesnt do quite what you want here

Answer (score 4):

You should use timeit module I think

```
import timeit
t = timeit.Timer('some_function(*args)', # code to run
                 'from __main__ import some_function, args') # initial code 
                                               #run before time measurement
t.timeit(100) # times to run
```

Comment: but what when my some_function has a parameter and I want call `some_function(some_object)` ?

Comment: You should prepare it in initial block and use it in timing block I think

Answer (score 1):

I agree that timeit is the de facto 'module' to run native timings on Python source.  However, if you are interested in doing some heavy-lifting in terms of profiling, you might find something like runsnakerun useful (a visualization tool for the profiler native to Python).

- [Run Snake Run Website](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/)
- [Python profiler](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/profile.html)

A snippet from runsnakerun (which really just uses data from pythons profiler):

> sortable data-grid views for raw profile information
>
> identity: function name, file-name, directory name
>
> time-spent: cummulative, cummulative-per, local and local-per time
>
> overall data-grid view
>
> (all) callers-of-this-function, (all) callees-of-this-function views

Just for added *yes I know*'isms... you asked for something simple, and this is WAY over the top.  But, I thought I'd share another possible solution in case you require additional information down the road.  And if you don't find it useful, maybe someone else will!

To get an output profile file that will run in runsnakerun, run something like:

```
$ python -m cProfile -o <outputfilename> <script-name> <options>
```

Alternatively, if you developing in *nix you can use [time](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm), but now you have added overhead and potentially lose some precision that the Python module *timeit* might offer.

Different needs require different solutions - just adding to your bag-o-tricks.

HTH